# How do i retrieve an Microsoft.Graph entity based on it's @odata.id field using the c# package

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'd like to fetch some info from microsoft.graph using only the @odata.id field. It could be a chatMessage, a message, a todo note etc.

This is the info i have to work with.

```
"resourceData": {
    "id": "1682300342848",
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.chatMessage",
    "@odata.id": "chats('19:2b1ab50f-ebed-41b7-9521-d528f4d40d37_eb077b2e-bbd9-4bad-a82f-420747e5f11@unq.gbl.spaces')/messages('1682300342848')"
  }
```

I can get the data back by calling the following url in graph explorer, but i'd like to do it using microsoft.graph.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats('19:2b1ab50f-ebed-41b7-9521-d528f4d40d37_eb077b2e-bbd9-4bad-a82f-1420747e5f11@unq.gbl.spaces')/messages('1682300342848')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats(%2719:2b1ab50f-ebed-41b7-9521-d528f4d40d37_eb077b2e-bbd9-4bad-a82f-1420747e5f11@unq.gbl.spaces%27)/messages(%271682300342848%27))

1. Is there a way to execute an odata.id query using the c# microsoft.graph client - Prefered
2. Is there a way to execute an raw query using the c# microsoft.graph client - liveable
3. Is there a way to find the existing clients bearer token so that i can make a normal http request for this data - Last resort

Comment: You can check this code snippet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request